# Bad border of image iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I use iTextSharp to add images to a pdf-document.

When I add border for image I see one-pixel part of Image (look at the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2cim.png)):

[image: screenshot]

It is visible when I use white color for the border.

How I can remove it?

My code

```
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rec = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(PageSize.A4);
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(rec);

using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("file.pdf", FileMode.Create)))
        {
            document.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("picture.jpg");

            pic.ScaleToFit(document.PageSize.Width, document.PageSize.Height);
            pic.SetAbsolutePosition(0, (document.PageSize.Height - pic.ScaledHeight) / 2);

            pic.Border = Image.LEFT_BORDER | Image.TOP_BORDER | Image.RIGHT_BORDER | Image.BOTTOM_BORDER;
            pic.BorderWidthLeft = 20f;
            pic.BorderWidthTop = 20f;
            pic.BorderWidthRight = 20f;
            pic.BorderWidthBottom = 20f;
            pic.BorderColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);

            document.Add(pic);
            document.Close();
            writer.Close();
        }
```

Comment: That's strange. I wonder if it's not an artefact of the viewer. Do you also see that one-pixel border when you print the document?

Comment: Bruno, yes this artefact-border print too.

Comment: @Valeriy Does the image have an embedded colour profile, as noted in [Inserted images have an unwanted border or lines on one or more sides](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01066_Inserted_images_have_an_unwanted_border_or_lines_on_one_or_more_sides.htm)?

Comment: @Andrew Morton, this problem is in all each pictures: .jpg, .png, .bmp.
Interesting: If I use borderWidth  for each side separately (pic.BorderWidthLeft = 20f; pic.BorderWidthTop = 20f; ...) there are some artefacts. But if I use only pic.BorderWidth = 20f there are not artefacts! I don't undestand this problem

Comment: Have you got an example PDF that you could upload so other people can examine it?