# ItextSharp/PDF - image border appears in PDF file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, itext

I really need your help! I have an issue creating a PDF file. I did the research, but found nothing that can help me. When I insert an image to PDF - a border appears around the image. I do not set ANY border and an image doesn't have any borders. When I resize the PDF page - the border can disappear and after other resizing it appears again. When I print a PDF page - there is no any border around the image. My code in VB.NET:

```
theImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(screenShotPath)

width = currentPageObjectsListSortedByZIndex(j)(9).Substring(0, 
 currentPageObjectsListSortedByZIndex(j)(9).Count - 2)

height = currentPageObjectsListSortedByZIndex(j)(10).Substring(0, currentPageObjectsListSortedByZIndex(j)(10).Count - 2)

width = convertPixelsToPoints(width)
height = convertPixelsToPoints(height)

Dim x = Convert.ToDouble(currentPageObjectsListSortedByZIndex(j)(8).Substring(0, currentPageObjectsListSortedByZIndex(j)(8).Count - 2)) + Convert.ToInt32(padding)

Dim y = Convert.ToDouble(currentPageObjectsListSortedByZIndex(j)(7).Substring(0, currentPageObjectsListSortedByZIndex(j)(7).Count - 2)) + Convert.ToInt32(padding)

x = convertPixelsToPoints(x)
y = convertPixelsToPoints(y)
y = Doc.PageSize.Height - y - height

theImage.SetAbsolutePosition(x, y)
Doc.Add(theImage)
```

This is the example of a PDF page:
[image]

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue? Thank you for any answer!
Sorry if my question looks weird.

Comment: Have you tried other PDF viewers (SumatraPDF, Foxit, Firefox, Edge, Chrome, etc.)? Also, you could use [PDFXplorer](http://www.o2sol.com/pdfxplorer/overview.htm) to see the structure of a PDF file, which may give some insight into where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I tried to open it in other PDF viewers but the result is the same :(

Comment: Have you saved the image directly to a file so that you can examine it carefully for a border? Is the image the only thing on the PDF page?

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320246/bad-border-of-image-itextsharp Are you the same person?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thank you for this link! That's not me who posted that question.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, you are right, this image is the only thing on the PDF page

Comment: Unfortunately the example image has been converted to a jpg so I cannot tell for sure, but the background of the r.h.s. one is not quite white so perhaps the PDF viewer tried to increase the contrast at the edge between #FEFEFE and #FFFFFF, resulting in a visible line.

Comment: ... and the not-quite white might be because of the image having a colour profile as noted in [Inserted images have an unwanted border or lines on one or more sides](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01066_Inserted_images_have_an_unwanted_border_or_lines_on_one_or_more_sides.htm).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I still have no idea how to fix this issue :(